# Cosine function evaluations are linearly independent?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, measure-concentration, lebesgue-measure

Let $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ be distinct points in $\mathbb{R}^d$, and consider the functions $f_j(x) = cos(w_j^T x + b_j)$ for $w_j \in\mathbb{R}^d$, $b_j\in\mathbb{R}$, $j=1\ldots,m$, and let $m\ge n$. I would like to show that the set of $w_j, b_j$ for which the matrix
\begin{equation*}
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
f_1(x_1) & \cdots & f_1(x_n) \\
f_2(x_1) & \cdots & f_2(x_n) \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
f_m(x_1) & \cdots & f_m(x_n) 
\end{array}
\right] \in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}
\end{equation*}
has full rank, has full measure in $\mathbb{R}^{m\times d}\times\mathbb{R}^m$.

Clearly it is true that the functions $f_j$ themselves are linearly independent on a set of full measure (the $w_j$ just need to be distinct), but I am interested in linear independence of the vectors formed by evaluation of these functions on a set of distinct points. Any help appreciated!

Comment: The set where this matrix has smaller rank is an analytic set, thus it is of codimension at least $1$, since you already know that your functions are linearly independent. Every such set has zero measure. I do not think that this question is appropriate for this site.